# Burninate specific event tags

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

[onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onload), [onload-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onload-event), [onunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onunload), [onbeforeload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onbeforeload), [onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onbeforeunload), [onbeforeprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onbeforeprint), [onchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onchange), [oncheckchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oncheckchange), [onmouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onmouseover), [onmouseout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onmouseout), [onmousedown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onmousedown), [onmouseup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onmouseup), [onmousemove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onmousemove), [onmouseclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onmouseclick), [onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onclick), [onclicklistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onclicklistener), [ontouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ontouch), [ontouchlistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ontouchlistener), [ontouchevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ontouchevent), [onblur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onblur), [onchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onchange), [onreadystatechange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onreadystatechange), [onfocus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onfocus), [onkillfocus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onkillfocus), [onselect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onselect), [onsubmit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onsubmit), [onerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onerror), [ontouchevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ontouchevent), [onkeyup-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onkeyup-event), [onkeyup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onkeyup), [onkeydown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onkeydown), [onkeypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onkeypress), [onsubmit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onsubmit), don't help much with categorization.

[events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/events) and [event-handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-handling) are ok, but specific events are too specific.

How does knowing that a question is about the `onload` listener help you at all? If you really wanted to, you could just search for [onload](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=onload).

To be clear, I'm happy with event tags that *aren't for specific events*

Example: [events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/events), [keyboard-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-events) (synonym: [keyevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyevent)), [javascript-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-events), [addeventlistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/addeventlistener), [touch-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/touch-event), [mouse-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mouse-events) (not created), [touch-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/touch-events)

Comment: Why? Sure you can be an expert in handling a keyboard press event...

Comment: Why are these" too specific"? What does it mean for something to be "too specific"? Why is that even a thing?

Comment: @JanDvorak You… can?

Comment: @CodyGray Most of these have less than 500 questions. My point is that they are minor tags and it wouldn't hurt to burninate.

Comment: @CodyGray "Why my [jquery] [onsubmit] [event] is not working?" Seems that whoever created those tags was trying to write complete sentences.

Comment: Let's just say that cross-browser compatibility is not easy. IE is getting better, but keyboard handling is _still_ not consistent. Even in firefox x chrome / keypress x keyup x keydown.

Comment: @JanDvorak [cross-browser] [internet-explororer] [keyboard-events]. Done.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm sure you must be an expert in handling a keyboard press event ;)

Comment: What's the difference between [onmousedown] and the name of a specific API? Or do you want to burninate all of those, too?

Answer (score 2):

I disagree that these tags should be burinated. They are not meta-tags with a wide range of possible subjects, but tags about very specific and well-defined events in html-browsers*. Sure, a question about [onsubmit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onsubmit) is also probably tagged with [events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/events), but because a question can be tagged with [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [programming-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-question) doesn't mean the 'wider' tag [programming-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-question) is only valid.

If a question is tagged with [onsubmit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onsubmit) or any of the other event tags it is non-ambiguous what this question is about. The fact that I know how onsubmit and onkeydown work doesn't mean I know how ontouchevent or a hardware interrupt (a completely different kind of event) works. I believe that for each of the event tags there are several on-topic questions that can be asked, ranging from when exactly an event is fired to what can be manipulated using information from this event. [keyboard-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-events) gets already meta-ish with a wide range of programming languages and devices and [events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/events) is non-sensical broad.

* Some tags, like the onkeydown tag, might contain other questions where a keyboard is involved.

Comment: But do people really want to find questions about `onsubmit`? I agree that they aren't meta tags, but that isn't the only reason to burninate.

Comment: @bjb568 the point is that you haven't given a proper reason for burnification. You're saying "They're too specific" and "they are minor tags and it wouldn't hurt to burninate", but I fail to understand what is the actual issue here.

Comment: @eis They don't help categorize the posts.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better response, but one that would require server programming, would be a way to link tags as related, perhaps with some sort of search toggle for whether to include related tags, or not.

Otherwise, some of these cases could reduce actual information/secificity in the existing tags. Lumping some of them together could make it harder to find specific content. On the other hand, some of the taggings may just be clumsy or redundant, but that's a per-question issue, it seems to me. For example, "onkeyup" does seem to me like probably close enough to combine with "onkeyup-event", for example, though I'm not expert enough (nor do I have the interest/patience to study the questions) to say for sure.

Another idea might be to add something like "Also see onhover" to the "hover" tag, or whatever, as appropriate. Unfortunately, it would take expertise and attention to do some of these well.