# Touch some event tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Please make [ontouchevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ontouchevent) and [touch-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/touch-event) synonyms of [touch-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/touch-events). They even share the same description, created by the same user.

Comment: What about [ontouch]?

Comment: You mean like [tag:onclick]? Not sure whether that's the same - `on*`-tags seem to refer to the listener itself (sometimes in specific programming languages, such as [tag:ontouchlistener], while `*-events` describe the more general concept. Btw, there's also [tag:ontouchevent] next to [tag:ontouch].

Comment: Gotcha. I was focussing on the wrong part of the tags.

Comment: Yeah, maybe we should start a *discussion* whether `ontouchevent` should not be merged with `touch-events`, but rather get `ontouch` merged into it.

Comment: Related:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268953/burninate-specific-event-tags

Answer (score 2):

We should either merge [touch-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/touch-event) into [touch-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/touch-events) or vice-versa, there's no need for both to exist.

We should then make [ontouchevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ontouchevent) a synonym of whichever tag we chose as the main one.