# Fixing the [onevent] and [event] tag catastrophe

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-synonym-process

Hello there fellow meta users.  I have a little request.

While browsing tags, I noticed there is quite a few that could be merged or even deleted as a whole...  This happens to be with "event" tags.  What I mean by that is `[on<event name>]` and `[<event name>]`, for instance [onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onclick) and [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/click).

1. [onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onclick) = [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/click): I think this could be deleted because it's just a small subset of many languages.  But since it's tagged nearly 5,000 times for each, that might not be possible.
2. [onmouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onmouseover) = [mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mouseover) = [onhover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onhover) = [hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hover): Since the `on` tags are less popular than the ones without it.  I think they could be made into synonyms...  You could either make [hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hover) and [mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mouseover) two separate tags (with separate synonyms).  Or, you could make them all a synonym of one tag.
3. [onkeypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onkeypress) = [keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keypress): These are the same, like the rest of the events, they should be merged and made synonyms
4. [onkeydown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onkeydown) = [keydown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keydown): Likewise, these should be merged and made synonyms.
5. [onkeyup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onkeyup) = [keyup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyup):  *sigh* again, merged and made synonyms
6. [onscroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onscroll) = [scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scroll)
7. [ontouchevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ontouchevent) = [touch-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/touch-event) = [touch-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/touch-events)([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270430/touch-some-event-tags)): I think these could be made synonyms.  But I also think [ontouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ontouch) should not be included.  Because I see ontouch as  a single method, while ontouchevents could mean multiple different methods of touch events.
8. [ontouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ontouch) = [touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/touch): This differs from #7, I think these should be seperate synonyms.  Because while ontouchevents refers to multiple events, ontouch refers to one event.  Therefore they're different.

---

What do you guys think?

---

**`EDIT`**

Some related posts in the comments:

1. [Touch some event tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270430/touch-some-event-tags)
2. [Burninate specific event tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268953/burninate-specific-event-tags)

As 1 mentions, the three tags should be made synonyms.  But I also think the ontouch and ontouchevent groups should stay separate.

Then, for 2.  That was one of the ideas.  But as the community decided, they should be made into synonyms instead of creating a "humongous catch-all-tag".  Which I agree now.

Then, just to clarify, I don't think burninating is the right option, as they do clarify what the question can contain.  So, instead of burninating them, they should be made synonyms.

Comment: Certainly not one humongous catch-all-tag. The separate synonyms look fine though.

Comment: @Deduplicator, I see.  It would make sense to keep the all separate.  But because they're so minimal it didn't really seem like they were that useful to me.

Comment: When you account for different input types such as touch there are over 50+  different event types which could make the event-handling tag very cluttered if it was all pointed back to that tag. Also with then separated out it can be easier to determine if you can answer a question since you know which event is in question.

Comment: `hover` is a jQuery event, whereas `mouseover` is a DOM event. It might be worth it to keep them separate?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan `hover` can also mean the CSS `:hover` pseudo-class. Which is much different than the `mouseover` event. So I also think they should not be merged.

Comment: `event`, `click`, `hover` etc are just bad tags. they are too broad that can be apply to many different libraries/technologies

Comment: Good suggestions. May I make the suggestion that you edit your question to be more specific, so that it can be useful when someone searches here in the future? *Lots of tag synonyms to be made* is pretty vague. How about adding *related to* or *in regards to*?

Comment: @KenWhite Is that a bit better?

Comment: [tag:onevent] should be apparently synonymized to [tag:one-vent]

Comment: @Gnat, yes, that would make sense, I was using `[onevent]` as a general term for all the events...  Kinda like `[on<anything>]`, I didn't mean the `[onevent]` tag itself.

Comment: see also [Touch some event tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270430/1048572) on `touch` event (handler) tags

Comment: Why was this marked as a "exact duplicate"? The post marked is trying to accomplish something else from what was decided...  That post is trying to burninate all of them, while this post is trying to make synonyms.  Plus, nothing has been done about the issue since that post.

Comment: @Jamen, I am by no means a tagging expert, but to me it looks like you could post the merge/synonym suggestions you're making in this question as an answer under the duplicate. They seem constructive enough, the consensus looks positive enough, and they can then be acted upon under the other question. And you *might* get a Reversal badge for your efforts.