# What to do if your post is unresolved, yet multiple people agree with it?

Tags: discussion, support

So, I made a post a while back addressing the problems a [[onevent] tags versus [event] tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285363/fixing-the-onevent-and-event-tag-catastrophe). (Which I also felt was flagged incorrectly, but oh well).

Lots of people agreed with me, yet the problem was never fixed, and it was flagged in the end.

How do I address the issue again without creating a new post?

Comment: flagged incorrectly *how*?

Comment: @Deduplicator, the post I made suggested creating synonyms, while the post it was marked with suggested burninating all of them.

Comment: Ah, you meant "closed as duplicate", not flagged for mod attention. Say so! Maybe edit to clarify and especially to differentiate it from the other one? Do so and you'll have my vote for re-opening for sure.

Comment: There, I added my opinion at the bottom of the linked question.  Address the difference between my post and the linked duplicate post.

Comment: Well, now it's re-opened. I came back just early enough to actually get to vote.