# Could we focus [blur]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Currently the tag description for [blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blur) says:

> The visual effect. And for some reason also the Javascript loss-of-focus-event.

Of 1.1K questions tagged with [blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blur) 248 are also tagged with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). Upon cursory inspection about three quarters of those seems to be about the event.

Clearly this is not right. I suggest the following course of action:

- Edit the tag wiki to be about only the visual effect, and explicitly not about the event.
- Retag all questions about the event with [onblur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onblur).

I would be happy to do this, but I feel that I should get some input from the community before I start working. Is this a good idea?

A pitfall that should be taken into account here is the possibility of questions not tagged with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) that are about the event (because they are not correctly tagged or are about a different language with the same event). Not sure how many of those there might be out there.

**EDIT:** Some people have raised concern about whether there should be an [onblur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onblur) tag at all. That is of course a valid question, but I would argue to keep it separate. Let me explain why.

To just remove the [blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blur) but do nothing about [onblur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onblur) would be strange. Either there should be a tag for the event, and then it should be used, or there should not be one. Doing both at the same time is not a solution.

If we should open up the question of whether [onblur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onblur) should be burninated, we get stuck in the bigger mess of event tags. As [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285363/fixing-the-onevent-and-event-tag-catastrophe) question demonstrates, it is complicated and that attempt to do something about it seems to have stranded on the sheer complexity of the issue.

To get somewhere I think we might need a divide and conquer approach. Doing this  one change is a small problem we can definitively solve. It might not take us to tag utopia (or save the universe from heat death), but it will at least fix one obviously broken tag.

**EDIT 2:** The idea of burninating all tags for specific events were discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268953/burninate-specific-event-tags), and not very well recieved.

Comment: Well, I did the last edit to tag-wiki and tag-excerpt when stumbling over some untaggings in the review-queue (as a quick-fix for later follow-up). And then I started my holiday, and forgot all about it. Thanks for the meta-post.

Comment: Do we even need an onblur tag?  What's so special about onblur that makes it different from other events that can occur in JavaScript?  Is it possible to be an expert in onblur?

Comment: That's the tag description? That's a little odd. It acts like we don't know why something related to "loss of focus" might be called "blur"... (think about it for a sec if you have to)

Comment: Developers regularly face a specific set of problems around managing blur events in form fields. Experience in handling these events may not qualify a person as an "expert", but some people are experts in building and using form fields in JavaScript. Perhaps `javascript` `blur` should be retagged `javascript` `form-fields`?

Comment: We already have [tag:javascript-events], [tag:addeventlistener], and [tag:eventlistener] tags.

Comment: @cimmanon Are you suggesting we should burninate [tag:onblur]? If we should to that, I think we should be consistent and handle all the different event tags at the same time. There are [tag:onclick], [tag:onkeydown], etc, etc. I don't think one should be treated differently from the others.

Comment: *Could we focus [blur]?*. No, we can only *[blur] our focus*

Comment: @cimmanon http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285363/fixing-the-onevent-and-event-tag-catastrophe See the first comment.  People didn't think it was a good idea when I suggested it.

Comment: better use [tag:image-processing]

Comment: @SeptianPrimadewa Perhaps questions about the image effect should also be tagged with [tag:image-processing]. But I think that is another question.

Comment: It might be best to make onblur a synonym of javascript-events (unless there is another type of onblur that exists?).  Blur itself should be limited to image manipulation.

Comment: @cimmanon Then I guess all tags for specific events should get the same treatment? And how do we handle questions about the events (generally named the same thing in all languages) that are not about JavaScript?

Comment: It's an odd case. I personally can't see a reason to need a tag that describes a visual effect, but i also don't use visual effects very often so what do I know. It's definitely weird to have one tag that serves two communities (ui events vs ui effects), but it only has 4 followers, so i guess it really isn't causing any harm, but it probably isn't helping the questions using it either.

Comment: @cimmanon I have updated my question with an argument for why we should keep the question of whether there should be an onblur tag at all separate from this quesiton.

Answer (score 6):

I interpret the upvotes and the lack of answers as a yes. Unless someone protest I will go ahead and start editing questions. Progress will be reported back through edits to this post.

Comment: There's actually a lot of comments, so I would advise not to. Specifically, do you really think onblur is such a good tag? Maybe just removing the blur tag from javascript questions would be better than retagging?

Comment: Perhaps the image blurring can be given a better tag. Something like [[tag:image-manipulation]].

Comment: @MatthieuM. I count that as protest and will not proceed. I will update my original question with some thoughts on that tag.

Comment: I agree with @MatthieuM. There are too many uncertain factors right now. What to do with all other event tags? Do we need onblur? If not, should other onevent tags also be burninated?

Comment: @Rolf Thanks for your input. Please see my edited question for why I think we should not solve that problem now. tl;dr It is to complicated and burninating them has already been suggested but shot down.

Comment: I am not proposing to burninate onBlur, as you say this is another topic entirely, however, the question remains on whether to switch from blur to onBlur or simply remove blur.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The OP of the questions were probably looking for the onblur tag and just tagged it by blur by accident because they were not careful. If we should not remove the tag from the ones who got the right tag to begin with, why should we remove it from those who did not? (I do realize that you are much more experienced on using this site than me, so I do apologize if I'm not making any sense here...)

Comment: @Anders: Do not mistake reputation for experience => I am experienced in C++, but it does not mean I know what is better for SO, especially as the guidelines on such things have evolved along the years! This inexperience is specifically why I was only re-phrasing the debate on "whether or not to re-tag" rather than directly proposing a solution "let's retag" or "let's just remove" :) And indeed, your argument for re-tagging make sense.

Comment: Yes, go ahead with the cleanup simply accepting that whether having [onblur] or not is a different battle, and for now it exists and should thus be used.